# Нарисовать кривую на CSS?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, svg, рисование

Подскажите, пожалуйста способ "нарисовать" на чистом CSS максимально похожую кривую с закругленными углами, как на рисунке ниже. Я пробовал через `border-radius` и обрезать круг через `overflow: hidden` но пока результат не устраивает меня.

[image: кривая]

Comment: Можно, но даже пример приводить не хочется, так как это будет громоздко,  нелепо и ненужно.... И тебе любой вариант не понравиться и не устроит.  Css это язык стилизации...   А не для рисования

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это жесть - но получилось - надо доработать , смотрите ...
Создаём один огромный блок , в моём случае это 500px на 500px, и что бы с эмитировать **border** ставим блок выше на 20px меньше в диаметре, но точно по центрам обоих... то есть другими словами белый перекрывает чёрный, и мы видим только чёрную полосу, делаем **border-radius** и вгоняем это весь *трешь* в угол родителя у которого **overflow:hidden** и так мы можем двигать этот блок куда угодно и подставлять куда угодно .. так же можем в ручном режиме его изменять... нужен js что бы это дело как автоматизировать...

Собственно демо на "лицо"

```css
.items {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 1000px;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}

.overlay {
  width: 460px;
  height: 460px;
  background: #fff;
}

.items,
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: -700px;
  left: -260px;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}

.items:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 55px;
  right: 55px;
  z-index: ;
}

.items:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 55px;
  left: 55px;
  z-index: ;
}

.item {
  width: 500px;
  height: 140px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">

  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Максим ну у тя и терпение))))))))

Comment: Мой друг, не забывай - "Нет пророка в своем отечестве"...

Comment: Это выражение означает, что человека не всегда оценивают по достоинству...  Это из библии)))

Comment: Спасибо, за идею. Немного доработал =) https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/KQPVQq

Comment: @BlackStar1991, костыли просто супер)))

Answer (score 4):

Не знаю, подходит ли вариант на svg (думаю, что не подходит), но я его приведу:

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 40 20">
  <path
    d="M10,10
       A40,40 0 0 0 30,10"
    fill="none"
    stroke="black"
    stroke-width="2"
    stroke-linecap="round"
  ></path>
</svg>
```

Не знаю, нужны ли какие-нибудь объяснения, но на всякий случай вот они:

- [`<svg>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG) будет содержать только один [`<path>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)
- `<path>` будет иметь [обводку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) чёрного цвета некоторой толщины, со свойством `stroke-linecap` равным `"round"`, что как раз делает закругления по краям
- Часть окружности будет рисоваться с помощью [дуги](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs):

  - `M10,10` — переходим в точку (10,10)
  - `A40,40 0 0 0 30,10` — рисуем сектор круга от текущей точки до точки (30,10), с радиусом равным 40

Comment: Спасибо, но этот вариант настолько очевиден, что не интересен. Ещё бы проще было сделать просто масштабированой png картинкой загруженой в блок как фон.

Comment: А надо обязательно через одно место, то есть через css? :) На мой взгляд,это сильно напоминает боевики, где мастера разных школ спорят, чей кунг-фу круче.  Нужно в паре использовать CSS+SVG/ и не стараться себя ограничивать: только CSS либо только SVG. Пусть каждое направление делает то, к чему оно больше приспособлено. SVG - кривые рисовать, CSS - стилизовать их. **diraria** (+)

Comment: @BlackStar1991  **Ещё бы проще было сделать просто масштабированой png картинкой загруженой в блок как фон** - не ожидал от вас такое услышать. Даже в википедии приводится, как основное преимущество SVG, перед png полное отсутствие искажений при масштабировании https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG